# Preserve a variable's value from one method to another method via a view in controller class of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in php. I'm doing a project on online bus ticket system.

In a part of the system i want to update a table of database. At first i want to display all the rows of the table which i have done in index method. When a row is selected it's attribute value(which is primary key) is caught in 'edit schedule' method. This value is saved in the class variable attr_value. There I call another view to receive updated information. From that view the info's are passed to 'e_schedules' method by form. But there the value of class variable attr_value is reset to default value. But I want the value saved in 'edit_schedule' method. How can i do it?

controller class

```
<?php

//$flag_edit_schedule = 1 ;

class edit_schedule extends CI_Controller {

    //public $flag_edit_schedule = 1 ;
    public $attr_value=1;
    protected $table= 'schedule';

    function index() {

        $data= array();

        if($query = $this->database_model->get_records($this->table)){
            $data['records']= $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('select_schedule_view',$data) ;
    }

    function e_schedules(){
        //$table='schedule';
        $attribute_name='schedule_no';
        $attribute_value=$this->attr_value;
        echo $this->attr_value;
        $data = array(
            'schedule_no' => $this->attr_value,
            'bus_no' => $this->input->post('bus_no'),
            'route_no' => $this->input->post('route_no'),
            'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time')
        );
//$this->database_model->update_record($this->table,$attribute_name,$attribute_value,$data);
        //redirect('/admin/admin_home');    
        echo $attribute_name;   
    }

    function edit_schedules() {
        $this->attr_value=$this->uri->segment(4) ;
        echo $this->attr_value;
        $this->load->view('edit_schedule_view');
    }
}
```

select_schedule_view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <style>
 table, th, td {
    padding: 5px;
 }
 th,td {
    text-align: center;
}
 table {
    border-spacing: 15px;
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Select Schedule </h2>

    <table style="width:75%">
    <tr>
        <th> bus_no </th>
        <th> route_no </th>
        <th> time </th>
    </tr>

    <?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $rows) : ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo anchor("admin/edit_schedule/edit_schedules/$rows->schedule_no", $rows->bus_no); ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $rows->route_no?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $rows->start_time ?></td>
        </tr>


    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php else: ?>
        <h2> No records were returned </h2>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </table>

</body>
```

edit_schedule_view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<h2> Edit Route </h2>
    <?php echo form_open('admin/edit_schedule/e_schedules'); ?>


    <p>
        <label for="bus_no"> Enter Bus Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="bus_no" id="bus_no" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="route_no"> Enter Route Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="route_no" id="route_no" />
     </p>

     <p>
        <label for="start_time"> Start Time:</label>
        <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" />
     </p>

    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />

    </p>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    <hr />
</body>
```

This is my first post. I have done this much by scrolling other questions and answer. But now i need a quick help because i am running short of time.

Comment: Exactly what you want to do? Are you trying to perform edit operation?

Comment: yes. I want to perform edit operation on a table.

Comment: Why have you been taken this $attr_value? I think it's not required.

Comment: To pass the primary key from 'edit_schedule' to 'e_schedule'. Is there any other to perform this action?

Comment: you have to get data from your id in the database in your edit_schedule and pass it on your edit_schedule_view. Than you are able to get back your primary key in e_schedule.

Comment: I am getting my id by "$this->uri->segment(4)". But I'm facing problem to pass it from "edit_schedule" to "e_schedule" via "edit_schedule_view" as you are suggesting.

Comment: Check out my answer. If you facing any issue comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make following changes:

**Controller class**

```
function edit_schedules($schedule_no) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('schedule_no',$schedule_no);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data['current_schedule'] = $query->result();
    $this->load->view('edit_schedule_view',$data);
}

function e_schedules(){
    $data = array(
        'bus_no' => $this->input->post('bus_no'),
        'route_no' => $this->input->post('route_no'),
        'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time')
    );
    $this->db->where('schedule_no',$this->input->post('schedule_no');
    $this->db->update($this->table);
    redirect('/admin/admin_home');    
}
```

**edit_schedule_view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<h2> Edit Route </h2>
    <?php echo form_open('admin/edit_schedule/e_schedules'); ?>

    <p>
        <label for="bus_no"> Enter Bus Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="bus_no" id="bus_no" value="<?php echo $current_schedule->bus_no; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="route_no"> Enter Route Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="route_no" id="route_no" value="<?php echo $current_schedule->route_no; ?>" />
     </p>

     <p>
        <label for="start_time"> Start Time:</label>
        <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" value="<?php echo $current_schedule->start_time ?>" />
     </p>

    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="schedule_no" value="<?php echo $current_schedule->id; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />

    </p>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    <hr />
</body>
```

Comment: I have done editing according to your suggestion. I bring some changes as I am not passing any variable to "edit_schedule" method. I am getting it by "$this->uri->segment(4)". If i have it then is it necessary to run a query? Don't I already have it? I just pass it to the view and as you are suggesting i make a hidden form. But still my database is not updating. I am posting what I have done.

Comment: We are running a query to get the all data of current_schedule if you dont want to do that than just directly pass schedule_no to your view. You have to pass your schedule_no to your model to update specific record.

Comment: I have added an answer prior to your suggestion. I don't know how to add code in comments.

Comment: You cant format your code in comments so simply paste it if needed.

Comment: Don't we need to pass the array to update? I am getting schedule_no perfectly and have done exactly what you did. But still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$attr_value` will always contain the default value because you are initializing the value inside class and no change in value is made using external parameters. You need to pass the schedule_no in the route to use it in your controller. I will recommend following changes:

Controller

```
function e_schedules($schedule_no){

    //$table='schedule';
    $attribute_name='schedule_no';
    $attribute_value=$schedule_no;
    $this->attr_value = $schedule_no;
    echo $this->attr_value;
    $data = array(
        'schedule_no' => $this->attr_value,
        'bus_no' => $this->input->post('bus_no'),
        'route_no' => $this->input->post('route_no'),
        'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time')
    );
//$this->database_model->update_record($this->table,$attribute_name,$attribute_value,$data);
    //redirect('/admin/admin_home');    
    echo $attribute_name;   
}

function edit_schedules() {
    $this->attr_value=$this->uri->segment(4) ;
    echo $this->attr_value;
    $this->load->vars($this->attr_value);
    $this->load->view('edit_schedule_view');
}
```

edit_schedule_view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
  </head>

   <body>
   <h2> Edit Route </h2>
   <?php echo form_open('admin/edit_schedule/e_schedules/' . $attr_value); ?>


<p>
    <label for="bus_no"> Enter Bus Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="bus_no" id="bus_no" />
</p>

<p>
    <label for="route_no"> Enter Route Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="route_no" id="route_no" />
 </p>

 <p>
    <label for="start_time"> Start Time:</label>
    <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" />
 </p>

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />

</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<hr />
  </body>
```

Please let me know if you require any help understanding the changes I suggested.

Comment: Thanx for response.
I am not clear about "$this->load->vars($this->attr_value)". Why don't we pass it as second parameter of load->view().
And it's not identifying $attr_value in edit_schedule_view.

Comment: yes, you can pass it as second parameter too. `load->vars` is just an alternate syntax and you can name it anything you want, not necessarily `$attr_value`